GUI closing unexpectedly
I'm using PyQT6, PyCharm and Python 3.11.
Very briefly, I'm trying to convert (mentally) from VBA to Python.
I made a GUI in pyQT6, let's call it test.ui. It has a number of buttons and a table. I convert this to a Python file using the pyuic6 utility. I now have a Test.py file in the same folder. All good so far.
I add
self.mybutton.clicked.connect("buttonpushed")  

to the Test.py script and tag on a
def buttonpushed(self):
  print("Button Pushed") 

This works great and as expected. My intention is to have a form with many buttons, so rather than including the def in the Test.py file, which will change every time I run pyuic6, I move it across to another file called ExtraBits.py and include this in to Test.py with the line
import ExtraBits

It still works as expected and print the words correctly.
Now my problem:
I want this button to hide a table on my GUI. So I added
self.mytbl.hide() 

to the buttonpushed procedure in Test.py and it works. If I add this to the procedure when it's in the ExtraBits.py, I still get the printed words, but the table doesn't hide and the GUI closes.
I've convinced myself that it is due to me wrongly referencing the mytable object in the imported ExtraBits.py file but not sure how to fix it.
I've tried every combination I can think of including the name of the main window object etc. I don't get any errors, just the hide() doesn't hide and the GUI bombs out, but only if in the ExtraBits.py file.
Re made the file in to minimal.py and ExtraBits.py to try and highlight my issue
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import ExtraBits

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 256, 192))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 260, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(ExtraBits.PushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())

and ExtraBits.py is
def PushButton(self):
    print("Button pressed")
    self.tableWidget.hide()


That signal connection is invalid, as it should not have any quotes. Then, please provide a proper [mre] of your attempt, even though I'm under the impression that you're trying to use the pyuic generated file as your main script, while the common approach is completely the opposite (see the official guidelines about using Designer).

I am indeed using the pyuic file as the main , I followed a youtube video that did it that way and as it worked first go I didn't complicate things any further.  You are of course right I also did the connector wrong in the text above. I'll knock up some minimal code and see where I get...

Unfortunately, as it is for almost any field, there are lots of YouTube tutorials that are just cr*p, published by reckless people believing that playing around with something for a few days is enough to make them "experts", completely disregarding the responsibilities that teaching involves, giving priority to accumulating views and subscribers instead of sharing knowledge responsibly (which requires time and patience, things that are rarely compatible with the rhythms of such video releases). In fact, on top of any pyuic generated file there is a clear warning about editing them, and I've »

» seen people explicitly suggesting to disregard it, which is an extremely irresponsible advice to give! That warning (which, I dare to say, was added following my own suggestion), is there for an important reason, which is to prevent the many issues that typically present to beginners when they start editing such files, which may also be your case. It's a common mistake, understandable for unaware beginners who may not realize the consequences of their actions on their own code, but unforgivable for such "content creators" that disregard the consequences of their actions on their viewers.

@ musicamante The internet is the biggest library you could ever wish for but with out any librarians to keep things in order. I learn so much from youtube videos it is quite an amazing resource, but as you correctly put it there is little or no control over what gets spouted and learners can easily go up the wrong path.. I actually prefer class room teaching.. << I'm just old probably :-)

That's a good premise. A teaching "target" awareness and our own capabilities as "knowledge sharers" is even more important. One of the major problems of the current "fame hunger" is that it often causes irresponsible awareness misconceptions. Not that those didn't exist before, but the current social media state highlights the issue even more. The real problem, as it always has been and probably will always be, is not how people learn, but how those whom they're learning from learnt on their own. Good learning (therefore, teaching) shows a reasoning behind the method, not the solution.

I think we agree on that then musicamante.  Any suggestions where I can go to learn how to make my code work ?  I was hoping it would be a real simple rookie thing of not referencing the object properly but as there hasn't been a flood of answers I'm wondering if it is more complex.  I did read everything on that link you gave me but it didn't throw any light on my problem. Well unless I missed it I don't think it did.

While this is a typical case that would make it a duplicate of QtDesigner changes will be lost after redesign User Interface, it may deserve a related answer.
The problem comes from the fact that whatever is done in ExtraBits has absolutely no reference of the context from which it is called.
Specifically, your attempt to use self is misguided:
def PushButton(self):
    print("Button pressed")
    self.tableWidget.hide()

This is for two reasons:

the usage of self is actually a convention; it could actually be any valid python name, and its purpose is to give a reference to the instance itself, and it is implicitly given and set when a function in a class is called from its instance, making it a method; see this related post to know the purpose of self;
given the above, the actual value of self is not what you think it is: it actually is the argument of the signal, which, in case of QAbstractButton.clicked, is its checked state (defaulting to False);

The above happens because PushButton() is a standard function, not an instance method, so there is no predefined self argument for it indicating the instance: it's a function, there's no instance.
Consider this:
def someFunction(self, *args):
    print('hello', self)

class Test(object):
    def someFunction(self, *args):
        print('hello', self)

someFunction('world')
Test().someFunction('world')

While the functions are called with the same argument, the standard function will actually print hello world, while the second, which is an instance method, will print hello followed by the memory address representation of the Test() instance (something like <__main__.Test object at 0xdeadbeef>).
When using signals with arguments, then, any positional argument that the function accepts is set with the signal argument values.
Change your function to the following:
def PushButton(self):
    print(self)

And it will print False. This is the final problem with your code: since self is a boolean, it obviously has no tableWidget attribute. This raises an AttributeError exception that is not managed, therefore causing the program to crash.
This is also one of the main reasons for which programs should always be tested outside of the IDE (as they are sometimes incapable of providing the full traceback) and in a context that shows debugging output: if you had run your original code in a terminal or prompt, you would have seen that exception immediately.
So, how to solve that?
One option could be to use a lambda and "send" the instance as the function argument:
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: ExtraBits.PushButton(self))

While technically valid, though, this approach presents important issues; among them:

you always need a lambda, making eventual disconnections to the same function difficult, if not impossible;
the instance must always be explicitly sent;

It may be acceptable for a single case, but as soon as the program increases in complexity, all this would make code unnecessarily complex and difficult to read, also causing more problems while debugging.
In reality, all this can be easily avoided as soon as the proper approach is used, which is to never edit pyuic files, but instead follow the official guidelines about using Designer: a real, separated main script should be used instead, with the pyuic classes eventually imported into it.
Use the following code as the actual main script for your program, and rebuild the UI file with pyuic (in this case, I named it TestUi.py, which is what is used for the second import statement):
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from TestUi import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.tableWidget.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

I strongly suggest you to take your time to do some research about fundamental OOP aspects, including classes, instances and how their members and methods work.
Some reliable PyQt tutorials can be found in the official Python wiki, and valid Python resource websites like realpython.com and pythonguis.com.

Thanks for a detailed and very helpful reply. Not only does it work (which is always a good thing :-))  but it has resulted in me looking at it differently. This seems a much sensible approach as to what I'd been trying to do.  Out in the wild lands of YouTube there also seems to be the debate on leaving it in the UI format and importing or converting the .UI to a .PY as we've done here.   I'm off to do some reading. Thanks again musicamante.

@perfo You're welcome. About the choice between pyuic files and dynamic ui loading, it depends on many factors, and both options have their pros and cons. For instance, the pyuic approach is faster at runtime, because once imported it behaves just like any other python class, while loading the UI file requires parsing it every time a new instance is created. OTOH, using UI files is more immediate as you don't have to regenerate python files for any change done in Designer (sometimes you just forget it). If loading performance is not an issue, I normally prefer (and suggest) the UI approach.

Understood, thanks
